# How do I force mono sound on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: linux, audio

My headphones broke so audio only works on the right speaker. As a temporary fix I want to force all sounds to play in mono in the right speaker.
I run Ubuntu 9.10.

Is there a way to complete this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Gnome's "Sound preference" by gnome-volume-control .

Follow is a screenshot from my Fedora. But this is from Gnome, not distro specified. Notice the "balance".

[image]

Comment: (This wont actually make it play in MONO. It will only play in one side of the speakers, but it will still be stereo. You will miss one channel of the sound. -HackerFinn).